# Change mouse cursor on button - normal to pointer

Tags: javascript, css, cursor

I have created on my site in js a "right side sliding menu". It works and everything is okay but when I direct my mouse over the menu icon, it shows me a normal cursor ([look at the picture in link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/65947165/askqu.jpg)). I need a pointer cursor without add any links.

```
#buttonu5815{

      transition-property: top;
      transition-duration: 0.2s;
      transition-timing-function: ease;

      -webkit-transition-property: top;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
   }
```

---

```
var theMenu;
var originLeft;

window.onload = function() {
   //Click to open on the Muse Icon
   element = document.getElementById("buttonu5717");
   element.onclick = openMenu;

   //save the Left position
   originLeft = document.getElementById("buttonu5815").style.top;
   //Get the Menu element
   theMenu = document.getElementById("buttonu5815");

   //Click to close
   closeBtn = document.getElementById("buttonu5822");
   closeBtn.onclick = closeMenu;
}

function openMenu(){
   theMenu.style.top = 0;
}

function closeMenu(){
   theMenu.style.top = originLeft;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just add `cursor:pointer`to your button class?

Comment: ok, works, thanks !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this CSS is what you're looking for.

```
#buttonu5815:hover {
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CSS on the hover event, just set the relevant class/html tag (e.g. for a li element):

```
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```